# When using the OLP CLI I get error: "Unexpected HRN entity type"

Tags: heremaps, here-olp

Using the OLP CLI, how do I determine the HRN to use?  When I take the HRN that shows in the console for my project and call

```
./olp app domain list "hrn:here:authorization::myorg:project/projectId"
```

I get the error:

```
 "error_description": "errorCode: '400288'. Unexpected HRN entity type for requested resource : hrn authorization:myorg:project/projectId",
```

(Obviously I’ve replace the actual IDs here)

I can't see any documentation that relates to this error message, or about how I determine the HRN to use. In fact this HRN is the only one I can find in the console.

(Cross-posted from Slack workspace for reach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is connected to the fact that you pass a project HRN instead of an application HRN. According to the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/open-location-platform-cli/user_guide/topics/app/app-domain-commands.html#app-domain-list) the command accepts only application HRNs.

```
olp app domain list <app HRN> [command options]
```

The HRN for the application can be retrieved using `olp app list`. The documentation of the command can be found [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/open-location-platform-cli/user_guide/topics/app/app-commands.html). For the case when the application has been created via CLI.

If you want get the HRN for the application created on the portal. Please use the following steps:

1. Go to [Access Manager](https://platform.here.com/admin/apps).
2. Find your application in the list of apps.
3. Open Developer Tools in the browser and refresh the page of the application.
4. Find `trustedDomainsEnabled` request and check the URL. It should contain URL encoded HRN as the part of URL before `/trustedDomainsEnabled` See the picture from Chrome.

[image]

I know it is tricky, but this is the only solution I found.

Comment: Thank you! There seems to be a problem with the credentials I'm using, when I run `olp app list` I get nothing back ( I had tried that previously too).
Using your developer tools idea, I can get the HRN, so that's a step forward. However, running`olp app domain list` for that HRN gives the error

These credentials do not authorize access for this operation

However, I have only one set of creds for this account and it's an admin, so something's not right somewhere. Will keep digging

Comment: I reproduced the issue with my application. I fixed it adding the CLI app to managers. Please run `olp credentials list` command and find the App ID. Go to the application page switch to `Access and permissions` tab. Add the CLI app as a manager. The `olp app domain list` should work.

Comment: Thanks - that seems to have done the trick